# Pass as argument a table name in a MySQL command line, in a shell script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, syntax-error, command-line-arguments

I would like to pass as argument a table name in a Mysql command line in a shell script here is my little shell script :

```
if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
    mysql \
        --user=genome \
        --host=genome-mysql.cse.ucsc.edu \
        -A -D hg38 \
        -e 'desc' "$1" \
        -B -N \
        | awk 'BEGIN {ORS="\t"};{print $1}' | awk '{print "#"$0}'
else
    echo "Error."
fi
```

So when I try to run my script like this :

```
bash Script.sh tablename
```

It returns the following error:

```
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'tablename'
```

So, few things for your own information:

- I have access to the database.
- The table exists in the database when I execute the command with the tablename directly in.
- I tried alternatively with "desc $1", 'desc "$1"', 'desc "$1" '... always return an error (either ERROR 1049 or 1064).
- the awk following command lines are not the origin of the problem.
- I also tried in Python 2.7 with subprocess, and it gave exactly the same error :

  ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'tablename'
- I tried to find some help on the web and maybe,it seems that MySQL do not permit to pass table name as argument.

Since I have multiple table to iterate on, I have no other choices.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `-e` must be a single string. You're putting the table name as a separate argument from `desc`, so it's being treated as the database name argument. Change it to:

```
-e "desc $1"
```

Here's my whole script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
    mysql \
        -A -D bbodb_test \
        -e "desc $1" \
        -B -N \
        | awk 'BEGIN {ORS="\t"};{print $1}' | awk '{print "#"$0}'
else
    echo "Error."
fi
```

Then I run:

```
./scriptname t_users
```

where `t_users` is the name of one of my tables.

I omitted the `--user` and `--host` arguments because I get them from my `~/.my.cnf` file, but I don't think it should make a difference.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I also tried this. it return the same error:
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'tablename'

Comment: The most annoying part is that the error return the database table between disambiguation symbols. it seems that mysql can not get over the fact that my argument is a string, and understand it as something to quote.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked for me. I don't know why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: what makes me think that it could be, maybe, a problem of type is the fact that if I replace "desc $1" by 'desc "$1" ' it returns an other Error : 

"ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"$1"' at line 1"

Comment: Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes, so that's sending the literal query `desc "$1"` to the database.

Comment: can you show me the script you tried ? 
the table I try to retrieve from UCSC is named knownGene.
and it doesn't work for me when I gave knownGene as argument in the command line.

Comment: ok my bad. indeed your answer work. I don't understand what I was doing wrong...
thank you a lot !

Comment: Ok so I found the source of the problem :  quotation marks. MySQL seems to not understand the same way those quotation marks " " and those one ' '. I was using those quotation marks ' ' instead of these ones " ".
Big thanks again to @Barmar .

Comment: These quotation marks are being interpreted by the shell, not by MySQL. Variables are expanded inside double quotes, not inside single quotes.